# MYSQL assigning "small", "medium", "large" based on count and number

Tags: mysql

I have one aspect of my process with products that sets me back time wise.

Say I have a list of similar named items in a collection but they have different sizes

```
id      base_name           sizing  sum_dimensions
16493   Core LED Pendant            18.00
16494   Core LED Pendant            18.00
16495   Core LED Pendant            26.00
16496   Core LED Pendant            26.00
16497   Core LED Pendant            34.00
16498   Core LED Pendant            34.00
732292  Core LED Pendant            50.50
732293  Core LED Pendant            50.50
```

I need to figure out a way to assign sizes in the sizing column. In this case it's "small", "medium", "large", "extra large". Sometimes, based on the count of unique sums, it can be "small", "medium", "large" or "small","large".

This is a large list of products. I can get a count of distinct sums where the base_name is similar, but I have no idea how to continue further. MIN and MAX only help with the extreme ends, but not the middle values.

This is the only part of the whole data set up process that's slowing me down when I have a list of 4,000 products.

Thanks.

Comment: Trying to understand.. for each base name you need to understand how many sizes of that product there are and then put the appropriate one in the size column, right?

Comment: That would be correct. So a count of 4 distinct sum values is "small", "medium", Large", and "Extra Large"

Answer (score 1):

you could use a case when  filter

```
  select 
    id      
    , base_name           
    , sizing  
    , sum_dimensions
    case when sum_dimension  < 20  'small'
         when sum_dimension  between  20.1 and 35  then 'medium'
         when sum_dimension  > 35  then 'large' end as my_size
    from your_table
```

Comment: That would be good if it's just this group of items. The actual real situation is I have a list containing hundreds of such groups, so i can't assign the case ranges individually.

Comment: This is primarly a suggestion  .. you could define some range based on class of product .. my naswer  is for give you the idea that you can do as you prefer  .. you could find the avg and then with percentage  fix the medium values and the others in small and large .. . You can do this using case when  .... end

Comment: if you post a comment on an answer   only the user that coment the answer  are involved ...(me and you)    so  ...  what do you need ?